# OSError in Geodjango: [WinError 127] : The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, geodjango

Im trying to use `Django` with `Geodjango`, I followed all documentation steps, but still got this error when trying to make migrations:

```
OSError: [WinError 127] : The specified procedure could not be found
```

The `models.py` is correct, I'm using from `geodjango` site, and this is my `settings.py`

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ci3qd6ti+d+#-4pae7d*)^8nmmgb2j@cacivgt8rdvsngu2$mj'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'world',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'geodjango.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'geodjango.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'test',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '*********',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }

}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And this is the error I get:

```
>>> python manage.py makemigrations

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\hades\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\meumapa\geodjango\world\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db import models
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\functions.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .fields import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\fields.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .collections import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\collections.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import GEOSGeometry, LinearGeometryMixin
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\geometry.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import gdal
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "C:\Users\hades\PycharmProjects\geodjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 47, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "C:\Users\hades\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found
```

I checked and all requeriments for `geodjango` are installed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ever found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Still looking for a solution in 2021

Answer (score 2):

You probably have multiple Python versions and there is conflict between them.

Try to install the GDAL on your virtualenv and ensure that the gdal202.dll is in your virtualenv context.

Also ensure that you installed the right compiled version from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal), using pip and inside your virtualenv.

The GDAL DLL will be in the gdal installation path. I use a code like this in settings.py to setup GeoDjango on Windows:

```
try:
    import gdal
    gdal_path = Path(gdal.__file__)
    OSGEO4W = os.path.join(gdal_path.parent, 'osgeo')
    os.environ["OSGEO4W_ROOT"] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ["GDAL_DATA"] = os.path.join(OSGEO4W, "data", "gdal")
    os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] = os.path.join(OSGEO4W, "data", "proj")
    os.environ["PATH"] = OSGEO4W + ";" + os.environ["PATH"]
    GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = str(os.path.join(OSGEO4W, "geos_c.dll"))
    GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = str(os.path.join(OSGEO4W, "gdal301.dll"))
except ImportError:
    GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = None
    GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = None
```

Comment: What do you mean with "ensure that the gdal202.dll is in your venv"?
In my case I used OSgeo4W to install it on my system (v3.0.4). I built gdal (Python) from source myself (the Wheels are not available for Python 3.7 and GDAL 3.0.4 and I can't install 3.1.4 using OSgeo4W). Unfortunately I keep getting this error.

Comment: On the compiled gdal, you will have the dll file. I edited the answer showing the environment variables you have to setup in order to have GeoDjango working on Windows. Change the gdal301.dll with the right gdal dll of your compiled version.

Answer (score 0):

**"OSError in Geodjango: [WinError 127] : The specified procedure could not be found"** This error is causing due to the Mismatch version of the D-Jango and the G-dal Libraries. Kindly visit the Official Documentation of the  Geo-Django to get the Details of Supported G-Dal version. Once you match and install the correct version things will work smoothly.

**Note:** There are some forums which says you can navigate to this Path
`"Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py"`
and open the libgdal.py Python file, then add the DLL name (say gdal303.dll) into the lib_names list. **This is not required though**

If you are using the Correct versions the required libraries would be definitely installed and present in the respective python files.

Here is the command that you can use to check the version

all the installed packages details: `pip freeze`

DJnago-version:  `django-admin --version`

Gdal version: `gdalinfo --version`